# Vue component isn't ready when displayed

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router, tailwind-css

I'm a beginner and started my own little project with laravel, vue and tailwind-css. Sorry for my bad english. I have the following problem: If I switch the route or reload the page, my form-component is rendering in a state where it isn't ready fetching the data and load the CSS classes I guess. When I switch the route or reload you can see how the form and all style-classes building up. That's what I don't like. I want to get this component rendered when it's in a ready state.

I added a litte gif where I reload the page many times, so you can see the issue.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6k4z.jpg (Gif on Imgur)

My code looks like this:
**EditProfile.vue**

```
<template>
<div class="wrapper">
    <NavbarAuthenticated></NavbarAuthenticated>
    <div class="flex ...">
        <Sidebar class="flex-none"></Sidebar>
        <EditProfileForm :user="user" class="flex-grow"></EditProfileForm>
    </div>

</div>
</template>

<style>
.bg-custom-blue {
    background-color: #F8FAFC;
}
</style>

<script>
import NavbarAuthenticated from '../authenticated/NavbarAuthenticated'
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar'
import EditProfileForm from '../components/EditProfileForm'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            user: null
        }
    },
    created() {
        axios.get('/api/user').then((res) => {
            this.user = res.data
        });
    },
    components: {
        NavbarAuthenticated,
        Sidebar,
        EditProfileForm

    },
}
</script>
```

**EditProfileForm.vue**

```
<template>
<div class=" min-h-screen pt-2 ">

    <div class="container ">

        <div class="inputs w-full max-w-2xl pb-20 pl-3 pt-9 ">

            <h2 class="text-2xl text-gray-900">Account Setting</h2>
            <form class="mt-6 border-t border-gray-400 pt-4">
                <div class='flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6'>
                    <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                        <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2' for='grid-text-1'>email address</label>
                        <input class='appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' id='grid-text-1' type='text' v-if="user" v-model.lazy="user.email">
                    </div>

                    <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6 '>
                        <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>password</label>
                        <input readonly class='appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' type='text' placeholder="**********">
                        <div class="flex justify-end">

                            <router-link class=" bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 border border-gray-400 text-black font-bold py-2 my-2 px-6 rounded-md" to="resetpassword">Passwort ändern</router-link>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="personal w-full border-t border-gray-400 pt-4">
                        <h2 class=" pb-6 text-2xl text-gray-900">Personal info:</h2>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Name</label>
                            <input readonly class='appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' v-if="user" v-model="user.name" type='text'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Straße</label>
                            <input class='appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-gray-500' v-if="user" v-model="user.strasse" type='text'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Hausnummer</label>
                            <input class='appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' v-if="user" v-model="user.hausnummer" type='number'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Postleitzahl</label>
                            <input class='appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' v-if="user" v-model="user.postleitzahl" type='text'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Ort</label>
                            <input class='appearance-none block w-full bg-white text-gray-700 border border-gray-400 shadow-inner rounded-md py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none  focus:border-gray-500' v-if="user" v-model="user.ort" type='text'>
                        </div>

                        <div class='w-full md:w-full px-3 mb-6'>
                            <label class='block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2'>Land</label>
                            <div class="flex-shrink w-full inline-block relative">
                                <select class="block appearance-none text-gray-600 w-full bg-white border border-gray-400 shadow-inner px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded" v-if="user" v-model="user.land">
                                    <option>Deutschland</option>
                                    <option>USA</option>
                                    <option>Frankreich</option>
                                    <option>Spanien</option>
                                    <option>England</option>
                                </select>
                                <div class="pointer-events-none absolute top-0 mt-3  right-0 flex items-center px-2 text-gray-600">
                                    <svg class="fill-current h-4 w-4" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                                        <path d="M9.293 12.95l.707.707L15.657 8l-1.414-1.414L10 10.828 5.757 6.586 4.343 8z" /></svg>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="flex justify-start">
                            <button @click.prevent="saveData(user)" class="mr-4 bg-green-500 ml-3 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-3 rounded-lg">
                                Änderungen speichern
                            </button>

                        </div>

                        <p @click.prevent="pushModal" class="flex justify-start mx-6 mt-4 text-xs text-gray-500 cursor-pointer hover:text-black">Account löschen</p>
                        <button v-if="showModal" @click.prevent="deleteAccount(user)" class="mr-4 mt-4 bg-red-500 ml-3 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-3 rounded-lg">
                            Account löschen
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<style>
</style>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'user',
    props: {
        user: {
            type: Object

        }
    },
    errors: [],
    data() {
        return {
            showModal: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        saveData(user) {
            axios.patch('/api/updateUser/' + user.id, user).then(() => {}).catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            });
        },
        deleteAccount(user) {
            axios.delete('/api/updateUser/' + user.id, user).then(() => {
                this.$router.push({
                    name: "Home"
                });

            }).catch((error) => {
                this.errors = error.response.data.errors;
            });
        },

        pushModal() {
            this.showModal = true;
        },
        hideModal() {
            this.showModal = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Put `errors` inside data return object, next to `showModal`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a conditional that shows the component only when data has been fetched:

```
<EditProfileForm v-if="user" :user="user" class="flex-grow"></EditProfileForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to achieve is Server Side Rendering. So when the page returned from the server, you already have the user in it and there is no flashing in forms.

In here, Vue does what it's supposed to do. Its fetching user when you load the page in the browser. It cannot perform the operation before the page is loaded in a browser.

Currently, with Laravel and PHP, you seem unable to achieve SSR for Vue. But you can simply show a Placeholder while the user is loading

Try something like

```html
<EditProfileForm v-if="user" :user="user" class="flex-grow"></EditProfileForm>
<MyProgressIndicator v-else />
```

You can create a simple progress indicator with tailwind and vue.

Or it will be nicer if you can use a Skeleton Loader like in tailwinds [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/animation#pulse)

Edit: There seem to be few workarounds for SSR with Laravel like this [one](https://itnext.io/universal-rendering-in-laravel-using-vue-js-and-ara-framework-7b6bc23644b1)